# Update default SSL certificate in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Our default SSL certificate is about to expire in our Azure account. We uploaded a new certificate, but we can't find where to update the binding. It's like there's no binding. We only see the list of SNI SSL bindings, but nothing for the IP based SSL certificate.

Any idea would be appreciated!

Stéphane

Comment: Have you seen the guidance for configuring this here ? https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-configure-ssl-certificate/#bkmk_configuressl   It shows how to configure SNI SSL and IP Based SSL.